# I am not able to place marker according to search

Tags: android, react-native, maps

I am trying to place marker on searched area in my project. Currently it has been placed to a fixed coordinate by default when data is fetched through API. Listing co-ordinates in API are also fetched properly but when I searched for a listing on the basis of area data is filtered properly but marker does not move, any solution to the problem?

```
import {  Carousal, Heading, Input, List, Map, Image } from '../components';
import axios from 'axios';

export const NearMe = () => {

  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState(undefined);
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [markerCoordinate, setMarkerCoordinate] = useState([]);


  const getAPIData = async () => {
    try {
      const url = "https://903f-202-47-60-211.ngrok-free.app/listing";
      let result = await fetch(url);
      result = await result.json();
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error`)
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
  useState(async () => {
    // const data = await getAPIData();
    // setData(data);
    try {
      const url = "https://97cf-119-157-85-150.ngrok-free.app/listing";
      let result = await fetch(url);
      result = await result.json();
      setResponseData(result.data);
      setSearchData(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error`)
      console.error(error)
    }
  })

  console.log(responseData)

  const onSearch = (text) => {
    setSearch(text);
    const filteredData = responseData.filter((item) =>
      item.listing_area.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())
    );
    setSearchData(filteredData);
    console.log(filteredData);
    if (filteredData.length > 0) {
      setMarkerCoordinate({
        latitude: parseFloat(filteredData[0].listing_latitude),
        longitude: parseFloat(filteredData[0].listing_longitude),
      });
    }
    console.log(filteredData[0].listing_latitude);
};

  const [carousalView, setCarousalView] = useState(true);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const toogleView = () => {
    setCarousalView(!carousalView);
  };

  const navigationHandler = (data) => {
    navigation.navigate(routes.VENUE_PROFILE, data);
  };
  //console.log(responseData);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <Map width="100%" height="100%" markerCoordinate={markerCoordinate} />
        <Input placeholder="Search area"
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        style={styles.input}
        value={search}
        onChangeText={text=>
          onSearch(text)
        } />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Heading style={styles.heading}>Things To Do</Heading>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toogleView}>
          <Heading style={{ ...styles.heading, color: theme.colors.blue }}>
            {carousalView ? 'List View' : 'Carousel View'}
          </Heading>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {carousalView ? (
        <Carousal data={searchData} onPress={navigationHandler} />

      ) : (
        <List data={searchData} onPress={navigationHandler} />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Map Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import {baseStyle} from '../config';

export const Map = ({width, height, style}) => {
  return (
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={[styles.map, {width, height, ...style}]}
      region={{
        latitude: 24.83959,
        longitude: 67.08204,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
      zoomEnabled
      loadingEnabled
      >
        <Marker coordinate={{
          latitude: 24.83959,
          longitude: 67.08204
        }}/>
      </MapView>
    
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    borderRadius: baseStyle.borderRadius(24),
  },
});
```

Comment: please update this code in any online editor like codesandbox.io and update here

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan my query got resolved by the answer given by Bala Vignes down below, I just one have one problem now when I am trying to fetch all my data back by searching for blank my app is crashing since it couldn't find marker co-ordinates for blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Map component you have set static values for the region change that into ,

```js
  region={{
        latitude: markerCoordinate.latitude,
        longitude: markerCoordinate.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
```

And in the Marker Component also you have set default values . That's why the marker is in static place,

```js
  <Marker coordinate={markerCoordinate} />
```

Don't forget to pass the prop **'markerCoordinate'** in the Map Component,

```js
export const Map = ({ width, height, style, markerCoordinate })
```

Try it and revert back to me .

Comment: Thanks! @Bala Vigness it works! thanks alot I was stuck in this problem for a very long time, thanks dude.

Comment: btw just another query, Can you suggest me how to pin point to the default location (which was set previously) again when all the data is fetched back by searching for blank ("")

Comment: my app is crashing on boot up since at the beginning as all data is fetched together of different areas and co-ordinates are defined on the basis of search so app crashes

Comment: Try to set the state variable to your default location as '  const [markerCoordinate, setMarkerCoordinate] = useState({
    latitude: 24.83959,
    longitude: 67.08204,
  });'

Comment: Thanks dude once again, I also set marker co-ordinates to default co-ordinates if search text is blank (blank search results in fetching all the data of diferent areas)